# Polymer 1.0: Do <script> tags go inside or outside the <dom-module>?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

#### Question

> **Which method of placing the `<script>` tags is "best-practice?"**
>
> - **Inside** the `<dom-module>`?
>
> or
>
> - **Outside** the `<dom-module>`?

Also, please answer:

1. Why?
2. What is the source of your answer?
3. What downside risks are there by doing it the "wrong" way?

---

#### Polymer Starter Kit: OUTSIDE

In the Polymer Starter Kit, the `my-list.html` and `my-greeting.html` files place the `<script>` tag **outside** the `<dom-module>`.

Like this:

```
<dom-module>
  <style>...</style>
  <template>...</template>
<dom-module>
<script>...</script>
```

---

#### Other Experts: INSIDE

However, I have heard and seen several examples from Google employees and Google developers that suggest the `<script>` tags should go **inside** the `<dom-module>`.

Like this:

```
<dom-module>
  <style>...</style>
  <template>...</template>
  <script>...</script>
<dom-module>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct answer is - it shouldn't matter. While the documentation is indeed as @Mowzer noted, this is just an example rather than a definition. At least some actual Polymer elements like e. g. [iron-image](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-image/blob/master/iron-image.html) have it outside dom-module.

The relationship between the dom-module and the object Polymer constructor defines is established through the 'is' property of the object passed to the Polymer constructor and the id attribute of the dom-module.

From [Local DOM guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/feature-overview.html):

> Give the <dom-module> an id attribute that matches its element’s is property and put a  inside the <dom-module>. Polymer will automatically clone this template’s contents into the element’s local DOM.

As a side note, you can also successfully use <script src="external.js"></script> to separate the html from the JS - I'm just guessing this is one possible reason for this question. The only drawback to this (AFAIK) is that in this case a vulcanized version of your element will show incorrect (offset) code line numbers for JS errors.

Comment: And some Polymer elements have no <dom-module> at all, e.g. <iron-selector> and <iron-ajax>.  They only have a <script> element.  The <dom-module> is necessary to define styles and <template>.  If your element requires neither then a <script> element containing the Polymer({ ... }) call will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `<script>` tags should go **inside** the `<dom-module>`.

[Per this definition in the developer guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/feature-overview.html).

Element definition

```
<dom-module id="element-name">

  <template>
    <style>
      /* CSS rules for your element */
    </style>

    <!-- local DOM for your element -->

    <div>{{greeting}}</div> <!-- data bindings in local DOM -->
  </template>

  <script>
    // element registration
    Polymer({
      is: "element-name",

      // add properties and methods on the element's prototype

      properties: {
        // declare properties for the element's public API
        greeting: {
          type: String,
          value: "Hello!"
        }
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```